# Setting an ImageSource in XAML to PackIcon Kind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I'm trying to put together a ribbon control and I like to use the icons in the IconPack of the MaterialDesign WPF Toolkit. Is there a way that I can get to the icon image itself?

For example: Using a Grid Icon, the code is `<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Grid" />`.

How do I assign that icon to the ImageSource?

Comment: Those icons are not images, they are geometries (so, colleciton of lines, circles etc).

Comment: If these are Lines and circles can't you just use a `ViewBox` to present it?

Comment: @XAMlMAX you can use `Path` to present it, or just use `PackIcon`, but OP for some reason needs `Image`. Provided answer allows to do that via `GeometryDrawing` to draw geometry.

Comment: Thanks @Evk. I didn't know what these `PackIcon`s were. This seems like an overkill though. While the OP passes vector graphics wouldn't `Image` control then convert that into a bitmap for display, thus making the use of vector graphics obsolete?

Comment: I really appreciate your effort in explaining this to me @Evk. Thank you.

Comment: @Evk Please note that a DrawingImage is not a bitmap and hence not raster graphics. DrawingImage is vector graphics that can be shown in an Image element.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Note the previous comment.

Comment: Yeah I was wrong with that "yes it will", good that there are always people like @Clemens on this site to stand me corrected :)

Comment: Thanks @Clemens. Does that mean `Image` control is not using the raster graphics and can present the vector graphics?

Comment: @XAMlMAX Exactly.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens that was really helpful.

Answer (score 9):

You could use a custom converter as suggested here: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks/issues/39.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:PackIconImageSourceConverter x:Key="PackIconImageSourceConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<Image Source="{Binding Source={x:Static iconPacks:PackIconMaterialKind.Grid}, Converter={StaticResource PackIconImageSourceConverter}}" 
       Stretch="None" />
```

You will find the code for the converter class here: https://gist.github.com/PhyxionNL/160a6f04e6083016d4b2a3aed3c4fe71

EDIT:
This was incorporated into `MahApps.Metro` as `PackIconKindToImageConverterBase`.