# C# WPF Image.Source with materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="NewBox"?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, material-design

does anyone have an idea how to dynamically get an Emage.
Spurce with the Material Design icon in C#?

For example:

```
TestImage.Source = new ... ??? MaterialDesignThemes... ???
```

Am I missing the connection somehow?
I've been looking for hours...

Best regard Bernd

I search a lot of time in the internet and found not the right...

Comment: PackIcon is not an ImageSource. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55418276/1136211) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46907366/1136211).